# When running svn up for revision, are all previous revisions updated as well?

Tags: svn

I have a working copy in svn that is at say revision 1000. We have revisions that go up to for example 1010. I'd like to update only to 1005, does that mean that 1001, 1002, 1003 and 1004 are also updated when I go up to svn up -r 1005?

Much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later revisions include all changes done in earlier revisions (unless it was explicitly undone). That said, revision 1005 will contain everything you've done earlier (1-1004).